# ignore css styles on certain type selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have 2 sites, http://1.example.com, http://2.example.com.

My issue is this : I am to dynamically add content to 1.example.com and 2.example.com, as part of this dynamic content addition I need to download and apply a css file via javascript. Now there is a `<hr>` tag in my dynamic content I'd like to style. When I apply this on 1.example.com, all works fine, but when I try to apply it to 2.example.com, the issue is that 2.example.com has a stylesheet that already defines stylerules for the `<hr>` tag. Like say padding. I don't want to override the properties manually. Is there a way to ignore `<hr>` styles defined in 2.example.com for my dynamic content and only apply styles I downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific. Learn about [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) to override styles.

You could, for example, add a class to the `<hr>` and style that.

Comment: Hi @bookcasey, The issue I am trying to solve is lets say I have a stylesheet lets call it styles1 and have `<hr>` defined with color:yellow; in 1.example.com and when I inject this into 2.example.com, if this site has a stylesheet call it styles2 and `<hr>` border is defined, I don't want the border styling, I could just define border in my style1 file, but my question is, is there way to not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

You may find parent div in your dymanic content,
For example: .parent-div hr{ your styles }